# Receiving regular updates from server

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

My app requires real time updating of information, i.e updates around every 20 seconds, and the size of the data can vary (can be >4KB).

What would be the ideal method of polling the server for data or even somehow pushing the data to the client instead? I'm guessing one of these methods https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html would be suitable but not sure which one is suitable for my needs. Are there other more battery/data efficient ways of doing this.

The app only needs to receive information when it is open and in the foreground.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using Sockets or could message   cause of making request every 20 sec harm  battery and Android system will force it to be at least 1 minute

Comment: [Firebase messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)?

Comment: @azizbekian I looked at that, but the data can't be more than 4kb so I don't think that would work unless I'm reading that incorrectly?

Comment: @Elsunhoty So Sockets would allow the server to push the data to the phone instead? How would it know what type of data to send as it also relies on the location?